# why mongoDb distinct and group return varies?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection, all the document contain a field 'hitword', but when i want to know how many different hitword in the collection, the two method give different answer:
db.getCollection('hitwords_daily_stat').aggregate({'$group'{'_id':'$hitword'}})    total 50 outputs
db.getCollection('hitwords_daily_stat').distinct('hitword'),total 152 outptut, and here's some of them:
the type of hitword is String, and I use utf-8

I don't know why the first output is just subset of the second

Comment: You need to provide this a a provable sample within the question itself. Try and post a small sample that illustrates the difference. It's likely that the type of field actually varies between documents, such as with an array in some cases, and this is the actual cause of the difference.

Comment: I use the command  db.getCollection('hitwords_daily_stat').find({'hitword':{'$type':'string'}}).count() ,just find that all the 'type' of the 'hitword' field in my collection are string. @Neil Lunn

Comment: It's not enough information. You need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45116750/edit) and show some actual data that reproduces. I still say some is inside an "array" because `$type` does not discern between `{ "a": "string" }` and `{ "a": ["string","string"] }`. But really this "should" be obvious in the `$group` output. You need to actually **prove** this. Show a sample where we can all reproduce.